# WebDav - 409 Conflict

Tags: list, webdav

I have a simple java application to upload files to sharepoint over WebDav. This works fine when uploading Picture and Word Doc libraries. However, it fails with `HTTP/1.1 409 CONFLICT` when uploading to Customized Reports and Form Templates libraries. Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: Both Customized Report and Fomr Templates are Base Type set to DocumentLibrary so there no difference in terms of Base Type.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that you may have multiple requests out there stepping on each other, thus giving you your 409 error.  But, i'm not a DEV so I may be off base.

The form library extends the base doc library to work with XML files, so the communication path may be changed.  I would load up FIDDLER / FIREBUG and watch what is happening.  That would also tell you if multiple requests are going out or something else funny.

The link below has more information about MS WebDAV Implementation with SharePoint:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff830430(v=office.12).aspx